# Using Regex Breaking a text on the last digit using linux tools like sed, or awk

Tags: sed, regex, awk

I have the following list that I want to break on the digit. For example:

**From:**

```
103Ru
103mRh
104
1041
```

**To:**

```
103
Ru
103
mRh
104
1041
```

I would like to use Regx with sed or maybe awk in order to achieve this result. But most of my approaches failed. I need some advice or possibly some solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's/([0-9])([^0-9])/\1\n\2/g' filename 
103
Ru
103
mRh
104
1041
```

The above regex looks for a number followed by not a number.  If found, it inserts a newline between them.

In more detail, sed commands of the form `s/old/new/` look for `old` and replace it with `new`.  In our case, `old` consists of two characters: `([0-9])` matches any number and, because it is enclosed in parens, it saves the value.  `([^0-9])` matches anything other than a number and saves it also.  Those two characters, if found, are replaced with `\1\n\2` which means the first match (the number), a newline, and the second match (not-a-number).

**MORE:** If we want to break at the beginnings of numbers as well as at the end, then we add one more substitution command:

```
$ echo xyz541wpk | sed -r 's/([0-9])([^0-9])/\1\n\2/g; s/([^0-9])([0-9])/\1\n\2/g'
xyz
541
wpk
```

The second substitution command is just like the first but it looks for the reverse pattern: not-a-number followed by a number.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two more choices:

1. `grep`

   ```
   grep -oP '\d+|.*' file
   ```

   **Explanation:**

   - `-P` : activates Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, which lets us use `\d` for digits. The `|` symbol, logical `OR`, means that `grep` will *first* try to match one or more (`+`) digits, and *then* everything else (`.*`).
   - `-o` : This causes `grep` to only print the matching part of the input line. A side effect is that if a line has multiple matches, it will print each of them on a new line, so it will produce the desired output.
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -lne 's/(\d+)(\D+)/$1\n$2/; print;' file
   ```

   **Explanation:**

   - The `-n` means, read the file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line. `-l` i) removes newlines (`\n`) from the end of the line and ii) adds a `\n` to each `print`.
   - `s/pattern/replacement/` : replaces `pattern` with `replacement`.
   - `(\d+)(\D+)` : Match one or more digits (`\d`) followed by one or more non-digits (`\D`). The parentheses `()` means that the matches are *captured* so we can then refer to them as `$1` and `$2`.
   - Taken together, the substitution will simply insert a newline between a string of digits, and the following non-digits. The `print` just prints the line.